# Task module with React component doesn't open

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a Teams bot (.Net Core 3.1 + Bot SDK 4.0) and I call task module from it to render my React app. A React app is a SPA located at the same App Service as a bot. It works fine at the local stand and at the developer's stand, but at the customer's test stand, after calling the task module, a problem arises.

At desktop windows app there is happening nothing at first time, after the second click of the button to open the task module, an error appears at the bottom of the adaptive card:

[image: Error at desktop app]

There is an error in the Developer Tools:

[image: Error at developer tools]

I also tried to open this task module in popup application mode, it returns an error window:

[image]

In the Developer Tools, in this case, I have the following errors:

[image]

When I try to open my React app from the browser or use it as a tab for my bot, it works fine. What should be the problem with opening it as a task module? Maybe I need to do some extra steps in the Microsoft Teams admin center?

Comment: It shouldn't be happening if it is working as a Tab. Can you share snippet of how you are returning the Task module and how you are invoking it?

Comment: I invoke Task module by sending task/fetch message after clicking bot card button. At bot I create TaskModuleTaskInfo with standard fields (Height, Width, Title, Url, FallbackUrl) and return it like this: `return await Task.FromResult(new TaskModuleResponse { Task = new TaskModuleContinueResponse { Value = taskInfo }});`. In the Developer Tools at Network tab (for popup application mode) I can see this invoke request and response with correct data (if I open url from this response at browser - it works fine), but task module show me picture with problem message.

Comment: Is it just not working for particular customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve the problem. I installed the bot through a local upload of the manifest, but then I found out that it was also added to the list of applications for our organization (at Teams admin center), and apparently there was some kind of collision between them. After I uninstalled the application from my desktop Teams and installed it from the application pool - the error disappeared.